# Change Datatype of json_value during select into so I can sum column

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in a table that is json.  It contains several columns within it.

Example:

- Row1:  `"sTCounts":[{"dpsTypeTest":"TESTTRIAL","cnt":3033244.0}`
- Row2:  `"sTCounts":[{"dpsTypeTest":"TESTTRIAL","cnt":3.3}`

I need to sum the cnt value for all rows in table.  For instance, the above would produce a result of 3033247.3

I'm not familiar with stored procs enough to master.  I thought the easiest route would be to create a temp table and extract the value into a column, and then write a query to sum the column values.

The problem is that it creates a column with datatype `nvarchar(4000)`.  It won't let me sum that column.  I thought of changing the datatype but not sure how.  I am trying `CAST` without luck.

```
 select CAST(json AS varchar) AS JSON_VALUE(jsontext, 
'$.sTCounts.cnt') AS PerfCount, TitleNumber 
INTO dbo_Testing_Count0
from PerformanceTest

select sum(PerfCount)
from dbo_Testing_Count
Group by PerfCount
```

The error message is:

> Incorrect syntax near 'jsontext'.

Any ideas?  I am open to another method to sum the column or changing the datatype whichever the experts can aid on.  I appreciate it.

Comment: The error is at `JSONTEXT`, not your `SUM`. You have `CAST(json AS varchar) AS JSON_VALUE(jsontext, '$.serviceTierCounts.cnt') AS PerformanceCount,` which makes little sense. It looks like you forgot the alias after the first `AS`. Also, never declare a `varchar` and **not** declare it's length.

Comment: Also, if `'$.serviceTierCounts.cnt'` returns a integer value, either `CAST`/`CONVERT` it in the `SELECT` or use `OPENJSON` with a `WITH` to define the structure of your JSON data.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll work on these and if I figure it out, post for others.  Appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you provide in your question is not valid... This seems to be just a fragment of a larger JSON. As your data starts with a `[` you have to think of it as an array, so the simple json path `'$.serviceTierCounts.cnt'` won't work probably...

Try this, I've added the opening `{` and the closing brackets at the end:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourJson NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
 (N'{"serviceTierCounts":[{"dpsType":"TRIAL","cnt":3033244.0}]}')
,(N'{"serviceTierCounts":[{"dpsType":"TRIAL","cnt":3.3}]}');
```

--You can read one scalar value using `JSON_VALUE` directly with a cast. But in this case I need to add `[0]`. This will tell the engine to read the first (zero-based index!) object's `cnt` property.

```
SELECT CAST(JSON_VALUE(YourJson,'$.serviceTierCounts[0].cnt') AS DECIMAL(14,4))
FROM @mockupTable
```

--But I think, that it's this what you are looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM @mockupTable 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YourJson,'$.serviceTierCounts')
WITH(dpsType varchar(100)
    ,cnt decimal(14,4));
```

The `WITH` clause will return the object in typed columns *side-by-side*.

For easy proceeding, you can wrap this as a CTE and continue with the set in the following SELECT.